# How do I pass multiple objects into model in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I do have some issues understanding the basics of Spring. I am writing a very simple discussion platform.

This is the GET part

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getThreadPage(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        if(threadRepository.existsById(id)) {
            var discussionThread = threadRepository.getById(id);
            model.addAttribute("thread", discussionThread);
            model.addAttribute("newPost", new Post());
            return "thread";
        } else {
            return "thread-not-found";
        }
    }
```

It works as supposed. The view (html) is able to access both thread and post objects via Thymeleaf.

```
@PostMapping("/{id}")
    public String addNewPost(@PathVariable Long id, Post newPost, Model model) {
        var th = (DiscussionThread) model.getAttribute("thread");
        th.addPost(newPost);
        threadRepository.save(th);
        return "redirect:/thread/"+id;
    }
```

This POST mapping is a bit problematic though. The object **newPost** passes without any problems (it is supposedly correctly mapped via Thymeleaf). However, I am not able to access the **thread** object which was given in the get request. I tried getting it as an method argument or via getAttribute method but nothing works. It always returns **null**.

My questions are:

1. Does the Model remain with its given objects/atributes throughout the entire session or does it clear after every request?
2. Is it possible to pass like that objects via view?
   These questions are quite theoretical, I would like to understand how does it work. I am obivously able to resolve that by recalling getting the object from repo by ID.

Comment: 1. Unless explicitly marked as a session scoped object it is only available during the request. Each request has a new model. Instead of storing the full object (do you really need it) you might be better of passing the ID around instead of stuffing the full object in the session.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me understanding that :)